# How can i deal with the justification of my text in tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, line-spacing, rowcolor

How can I center the two last columns of my text in the next table?

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,x11names,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,caption,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc,textfont=it}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{totcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption[Actividades diseñadas]{Actividades diseñadas para la elaboración de habilidades de observación}
    \label{tab:Actdis}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.22\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.17\linewidth}p{0.14\linewidth} @{}}
        \toprule
        Actividad & Descripción & Forma de trabajo &  Archivos recuperados\\
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}
        1. Descripción    & Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 37\\
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}& Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Grupal & 13 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}2. Interpretación & Elaboración de observación a partir de conceptos teóricos del video de interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 30 \\
        3. Indicadores    & Elaboración de indicadores de diálogicidad en el aula & Individual & 31 \\
        4. Análisis       & Análisis de un video con los indicadores de dialogicidad de los estudiantes & Individual & 22 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}5. Análisis con transcripción & Análisis del video con la transcripción &  Individual & 22 \\
        6. Resumen        & Elaboración de un resumen del programa Aprendiendo Juntos & Individual & 24\\
        7. Página LCC     & Propuestas de diseño para la página del Laboratorio de Cognición y Comunicación & Individual & 15 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}8. Trabajo final  & Análisis con el sistema de caracterización diálogica mediante la herramienta multimedia & Grupal & 13 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which rows should be colored, and with which color(s)? I see you're already loading the `xcolor` and (indirectly) the `colortbl` packages. Have you looked into using the latter package's `\rowcolor{<some color>}` macro.

Comment: You should ***not*** load `typearea` separately if using a KOMA class. The documentation is quite explicit on this point. Your class will load it directly with the appropriate options. You should remove the line trying to load it again.

Comment: Are you using all those packages? `xkeyval` is usually loaded by classes or packages to manage key-value options. It is not usually loaded in documents as there is usually no use for it. Also, have you read `booktabs` discussion of typesetting professional-quality tables? You are loading it, but taking none of its advice ;).

Comment: @cfr thanks for your comments. I take them into account.

Comment: @Mico thanks, i´m learning to use them well.

Comment: With your latest edit, you appear to have completely changed the title and content of your posting. As a result, the existing answer (by @Bernard) has been rendered utterly meaningless and irrelevant since it, unsurprisingly, addresses the original form of your query. Please consider (a) restoring the original form of your posting here and (b) creating a *new posting* that mentions the new issue, or issues, you're looking to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known problem that row colors doesn't work with longtable:

[image]

However, `\rowcolor` in front of individual rows runs nicely.

**Added:**

There is a problem using `booktabs` with `rwcolor(s)`: as it adds some vertical padding around its rules, there appears white strips that may be unwanted. In such a case I propose another solution, based on the `boldline` and `cellspace` packages: the first package , as its names indicates, allows for variable-width lines (including vertical lines, if one wants to use them); the second adds some minimal vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells. The last two columns centring problem is solved with `makecell` and its `\thead` command, thats allows for common formatting and line breaking in columnheads; by default, its content is centred (vertically and horizontally) whatever the column type in which it is used.

With the following code, you can compare:

```
    \documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,x11names,DIV=10]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{typearea}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names, table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}

    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{array,caption,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=sc,textfont=it}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
    %\usepackage{totcount}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}
    \usepackage{boldline}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption[Actividades diseñadas]{Actividades diseñadas para la elaboración de habilidades de observación}
  \label{tab:Actdis}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}lXccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Actividad & Descripción & \thead{Forma\\de trabajo} & \thead{Archivos\\ recuperados}\\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}
    1. Descripción & Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 37 \\
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white} & Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Grupal & 13 
\\\addlinespace[4pt]
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}2. Interpretación & Elaboración de observación a partir de conceptos teóricos del video de interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 30 \\
        3. Indicadores & Elaboración de indicadores de diálogicidad en el aula & Individual & 31 \\
        4. Análisis & Análisis de un video con los indicadores de dialogicidad de los estudiantes & Individual & 22 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}5. Análisis con transcripción & Análisis del video con la transcripción & Individual & 22 \\
        6. Resumen & Elaboración de un resumen del programa Aprendiendo Juntos & Individual & 24 \\
        7. Página LCC & Propuestas de diseño para la página del Laboratorio de Cognición y Comunicación & Individual & 15 \\
        \rowcolor{gray!25!white}8. Trabajo final & Análisis con el sistema de caracterización diálogica mediante la herramienta multimedia & Grupal & 13 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption[Actividades diseñadas]{Actividades diseñadas para la elaboración de habilidades de observación}
  \label{tab:Actdis}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}lS{X}ccc@{}}
    \hlineB{2}
    Actividad & Descripción & \thead{Forma\\de trabajo} & \thead{Archivos\\ recuperados}\\
    \hlineB{1.5}
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}
    1. Descripción & Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 37 \\
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white} & Elaboración de observación del video de Interacción madre-hijo & Grupal & 13 \\\addlinespace[4pt]
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}2. Interpretación & Elaboración de observación a partir de conceptos teóricos del video de interacción madre-hijo & Individual & 30 \\
    3. Indicadores & Elaboración de indicadores de diálogicidad en el aula & Individual & 31 \\
    4. Análisis & Análisis de un video con los indicadores de dialogicidad de los estudiantes & Individual & 22 \\
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}5. Análisis con transcripción & Análisis del video con la transcripción & Individual & 22 \\
    6. Resumen & Elaboración de un resumen del programa Aprendiendo Juntos & Individual & 24 \\
    7. Página LCC & Propuestas de diseño para la página del Laboratorio de Cognición y Comunicación & Individual & 15 \\
    \rowcolor{gray!25!white}8. Trabajo final & Análisis con el sistema de caracterización diálogica mediante la herramienta multimedia & Grupal & 13 \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the example, but how did you do it? I try to make it easy

Comment: @Sheltis: I've modified my answer to take your new code into account, and I propose two solutions. I also slightly improved your code. Btw, it is needless to load longtable if you load ltablex: the latter does it for you. Also the `usenames` option for `xcolor` is obsolete.